# AJAX query works 50+ times then crashes javascript

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I have some javascript that works 50+ consecutive times and then crashes the browser.  I have 2 ajax calls in the function that run php scripts returning json data.  The error handler code shows that it is the inner (second) ajax call that returns an Uncaught Error. Then I get a 408 TImeout alert message saying "Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is the code:

```
function doTask(btnID)
{
    var data =
    {      
        "action": "test"    
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "doTask.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(data) 
        {
            var result = data['Result'];
            document.getElementById('Result').value=result;
            // Update result
            var balance = result;
            document.getElementById('txtAcctBalance').value = balance.toFixed(8);
            var post_data = { amount: balance};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "updateAcctBalance.php",
                data: post_data,
                async: false,
                error: function(jqXHR, exception) 
                {
                    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                        alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');            
                    } 
                    else if (jqXHR.status == 404) 
                    {
                        alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                    }
                    else if (jqXHR.status == 500)
                    {
                        alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                    }
                    else if (exception === 'parsererror') 
                    {
                        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                    }
                    else if (exception === 'timeout')
                    {
                        alert('Time out error.');
                    } 
                    else if (exception === 'abort')
                    {
                        alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);            
                    }    
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) 
        {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');            
            } 
            else if (jqXHR.status == 404) 
            {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            }
            else if (jqXHR.status == 500)
            {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            }
            else if (exception === 'parsererror') 
            {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            }
            else if (exception === 'timeout')
            {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } 
            else if (exception === 'abort')
            {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);            
            }
        }
    });
    return false;  
}
```

Comment: maybe your server is not responding?

Comment: Check updateAcctBalance.php. there might be some memory leaks in the processing in that page.

Comment: Ibu, is there a way I can confirm if the server is responding?

Comment: Guanxi, I don't believe there is any memory leak in the php code.  Here it is:

Comment: <?php
include 'db_connect.php';
 $amount = $_POST['amount'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $my_upd_stmt = 'UPDATE members SET AccountBalance="'.$amount.'" WHERE email="'.$email.'"';
 if ($upd_stmt = $mysqli->prepare($my_upd_stmt))
 {
  $upd_stmt->execute();
  mysqli_stmt_close($upd_stmt);
  $arr = array('Result' => 'Success', 'Email' => $email, 'Amount' => $amount, 'Stmt' => $my_upd_stmt);
 }
 else
 {
  $arr = array('Result' => 'Fail', 'Email' => $email, 'Amount' => $amount, 'Stmt' => $my_upd_stmt);
 }
 echo json_encode($arr);
?>

Comment: Guanxi, sorry, the code is not formatted

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use always Try Catch method in ajax php scripts, and send back the error data as well to the js as it would be normal execution. 
Dont use too many database connection, because the number of connections are limited!
You should use a temp file to store all temporary data coming from js as a queue (with timestamp), and you should use a collector script in php, that reads the latest queue files, and evaulate them, if they contains more, than XX records or whatever, and saves all the queued data into the database at once.